# Read json-data from url, but it would not viewed

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a api that give me the follong response:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Learn Grinding"
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "See the messure".  
}]
```

and in my view I like to view this in a list. Later I like to save it into Core Data. But for testing, i just like to see the values in a list. But there is nothing to see :(

The list is empty. With the same content I try to use the Apple-Example with the itunes-List and this work in this ViewController.

With the first Button I test, if I can add a value to the database, and this works fine. Only the List of the json-data would not be read and viewed.

```
    import SwiftUI

    struct Response: Codable {
        var results: [Result]
    }

    struct Result: Codable {
        var id: Int
        var title: String
    }

    struct TutorialsView: View {
        @StateObject var viewRouter: ViewRouter
        @State private var results = [Result]()
        
        @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
        
        @FetchRequest(
            entity: Tutorials.entity(),
            sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Tutorials.title, ascending: true)]
        ) var tutorials: FetchedResults<Tutorials>
        
        var body: some View {
            VStack {
                Text("Tutorials")
                    .bold()
                
                Button(action: {
                    let tutorial = Tutorials(context: managedObjectContext)
                    tutorial.title = "Describe how to messure"
                    PersistenceController.shared.save()
                }, label: {
                    Text("Add Tutorial")
                })
                
                List {
                    ForEach(tutorials, id:\.self) { tutorial in
                        Text("\(tutorial.title ?? "Unknown")")
                    }
                }
                
                List(results, id: \.id) { item in
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text(item.title)
                            .font(.headline)
                    }
                }
                .task {
                    await loadData()
                }
                
            }
        }
        
        func loadData() async {
            guard let url = URL(string: "https://example.org") else {
                print("Invalid URL")
                return
            }
            
            do {
                let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
                if let decodedResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data) {
                    results = decodedResponse.results
                }
            } catch {
                print("Invalid data")
            }
        }
    }

    struct TutorialsView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            TutorialsView(viewRouter: ViewRouter())
        }
    }
```

When I change the url from the itunes to my own, I got this error in the console:

```
2022-02-17 14:36:19.868821+0100 GrindingCalculator[2460:27599] [boringssl] 
boringssl_metrics_log_metric_block_invoke(151) Failed to log metrics
```

I also try to use a iPhone and install it on this device and there also would be nothing viewed.

Can you see, where my mistake is?

Comment: The given JSON is an array without an enclosing dictionary. Decode `[Result].self` And the error is a warning and has nothing to do with your issue.

Comment: What you mean with enclosing dictionary?

Comment: Your data model matches `{"results":[{"id": 1...` but there is no key `results`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I get it and it works